# How to use dynamic actions in Oracle Apex cards?

Tags: oracle-apex-18.2

In Card template, I have a button which should perform some action (eg. PL/SQL code).

I followed the below link:
http://www.laureston.ca/2019/03/29/drool-worthy-apex-cards-with-images-and-buttons/

I have tried the steps and dynamic action is not working as mentioned. I am in need of more explanation to proceed this.

Answer (score 1):

Is your card template a apex list? If it is then you can add custom attributes to your links.

[image]

Create a dynamic action on click

[image]

Result looks like this

[image]

Comment: It is not a APEX list.. It is a card template in Classic report. I wanted to perform action on click of a button in the card.